# First View not visible when two successives setContentView applied

Tags: android

During loading of my android application i want to show a logo during the first 2,3 seconds of launching, I think it's less ugly than just seeing a UI after launching.
So in my code i make first a setContentView with the logo (splash) and after a setContentView with the UI (main).
The pb is instead of seeing the logo screen I just see a black screen.
I am doing that in main thread so I don't understand.
Do you have an explanation of the problem and if possible a workaround ?

The not working well onCreate() of the activity   is the following (black screen during 5 seconds and after can see the UI, no exception thrown) :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash); //doesn't work
    Log.i(TAG, Thread.currentThread().getName());
    //this.r
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Log.i(TAG, Thread.currentThread().getName() + e.toString() );
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.main); //work OK
}
```

}

if I just left the class with the code below there is no problem  I can see the "first" and only view :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash); //work OK
```

}
}

Comment: thread.sleep() is nearly always evil. It is *always* evil on the main thread.  Remember also that the UI is drawn after onCreate().  You should use a separate Activity for your splash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `TimerTask` instead of using `Thread.sleep` for making wait in main UI thread as:

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // use runOnUiThread for Updating Ui elements
        Your_Activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 // set Activity Next layout Here
                setContentView(R.layout.main);
            }
        });
    }
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 4):

> The pb is instead of seeing the logo screen I just see a black screen.

`Thread.sleep()` is the wrong approach. You are preventing *everything* from happening including showing your splash screen.

> The not working well onCreate() of the activity is the following (black screen during 5 seconds and after can see the UI, no exception thrown)

The layout is only displayed *after* `onResume()` is called, so by blocking the UI Thread in `onCreate()` you have created the blank screen. Then when the Thread resumes both layouts are drawn, but you'll never see the splash screen since the next `setContentView()` is called a few milliseconds later.

---

While the idea of using a splash screen is debatable, you should use a callback to change layouts after five seconds. Use a Handler and Runnable to change screens.

To insert my personal opinion, I would reject any app that takes 5 seconds to load. I have better things to do than look at a logo even for 2-3 seconds every time I open the app.

---

While I like ρяσѕρєя K's answer, I'll play devil's advocate. I prefer to use the root View's built-in handler:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    findViewById(android.R.id.content).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I remember a great debate over splash screens in an old question, if anyone can find the link I'll be appreciative.

Comment: This is a good argument against splash screens http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=632

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, now i understand the cause and the solution of ρяσѕρєя K works perfectly.

Comment: @sam "To insert my personal opinion, I would reject any app that takes 5 seconds to load."i agree, i just use 5 seconds for testing purpose.